# Keep object alive until a background task finishes

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to implement a method that executes a task in the background and then calls a block on the main thread:

```
+ (void)migrateStoreWithCompletionHandler:(MigrationControllerCompletion)completion
{
    MigrationController *controller = [[MigrationController alloc] initWithCompletionBlock:completion];

    [controller migrateStore];
}
```

This is the `-initWithCompletionBlock:` method:

```
- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(MigrationControllerCompletion)completion
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _completion = [completion copy];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The background work happens in `-migrateStore`. The problem is that ARC releases `controller` after `[controller migrateStore]`. Because `controller` is the object that holds onto the block, I am not able to ever call it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the dreaded "retain cycle" in your favor.

Basically, the controller object is strongly referencing its _completion iVar, so if you make that block strongly reference `self` then you have a retain cycle, which keeps the object alive for as long as you want.

The pragmas temporarily silence the retain cycle warning.

You can then manually break the retain cycle by setting the completion block to nil after calling the handler.

```
- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(MigrationControllerCompletion)completion
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _completion = ^(BOOL success) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"
            if (completion) completion(self, success);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
            _completion = nil;
        };
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then, in your code, when you want to call the completion handler, you don't have to pass `self` because it's already there...

```
_completion(success);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider having the class containing `+migrateStoreWithCompletionHandler:` keep track of all the generated MigrationController instances in a private array or similar. That would keep `controller` from being deallocated too early, and allow you to call your completion block.

You'd need to find a way to release them later, however, to avoid slowly growing your memory usage as you make MigrationControllers. You might consider posting a notification from the controller at the end of `-migrateStore` after you call the completion block, then having your factory class listen for that notification and deallocate the appropriate controller. (You could also get similar behavior with a delegation pattern, if you were so inclined.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `+migrateStoreWithCompletionHandler:` however is only ever called once right after launch.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only true limitation of ARC that I've dealt with so far. There are easy ways to work around it, though:

1) You can create a static variable for the `MigrationController` object and set it to `nil` when the completion block is invoked.

2) **Only do this when you *really* know what you're doing!**
Use `CFRetain()` and `CFRelease()` directly:

```
+ (void)migrateStoreWithCompletionHandler:(MigrationControllerCompletion)completion
{
    MigrationController *controller = [[MigrationController alloc] initWithCompletionBlock:^(MigrationController *migrationController, BOOL finished, ...) {
        if (completion != nil)
            completion(migrationController, finished, ...);

         CFRelease((__bridge void *)migrationController);
    }];

    [controller migrateStore];

    // Make 'controller' live until the completion block is invoked
    CFRetain((__bridge void *)controller);
}
```

Comment: Using CF calls worked, thanks. Does feel a little hacky though :)

Comment: This violates memory management guidelines and is wrong. You should never need to release something you didn't retain in the same function.

Comment: You're wrong. Only comment when you really understand memory management, please.

Comment: @FabianKreiser He's half right: this does violate memory management guidelines.  He's half wrong, because they are just guidelines.  But I'd still consider this an EXTREMELY dangerous approach, especially since it totally breaks every advantage given by ARC.