# iOS: Blocks and ivars

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

In a lot of question it is asked if its ok to use **self** in **blocks**. The answer is no, to avoid retain cycle.

Now when i use an "ivar" in my block in my `UIViewController` it should be fine. But when i use:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_customCell setChangedValueBlock:^{
        if(_object != nil){
            NSLog(@"This is a sample");
        }
    }];
}
```

The `dealloc` method never called:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc");
}
```

When i remove the **`if(_object != nil){`**, the `dealloc` method is called.

Should i make weak reference to the `_object` before passing it to the block?

Comment: Your use of a logged `dealloc` is just the right way to test this. Well done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an ivar (property, whatever) is exactly like using self - you have implicitly used self. You need to do the [weak-strong dance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16453305/341994).

It would be much better to pass thru a property, though, because it can be made thread-safe and because accessing an instance variable directly on a released weak reference will cause your device to explode.

Comment: Yes your right, didn't thought of that. Thanks!